# Powershell. Выборка файлов по самой новой дате

Tags: сортировка, дата, cmd, powershell

Необходимо из одной папки (с кучей подпапок) выбрать самые новые файлы и скопировать их в другую папку. С копированием я разобрался, а вот как выбрать именно те файлы что нужны - не пойму.

Поиск подсказал: `Get-ChildItem | Where-Object{$_.CreationTime.Day -like "23"}`. Но это именно по конкретному дню выборка.

Не подскажете куда поглядеть, чтобы не брать все даты файлов, сортировать, а потом выбирать? Если по другому никак то как это сделать быстрее? Просто файлов крайне много, поэтому такой скрипт будет обрабатываться очень долго.

Использовать что-либо, кроме Powershell и cmd - нельзя.

Comment: чтобы не брать все даты файлов, сортировать, а потом выбирать?  непонятен вопрос. как вы будете определять, что файл новый? 
Дополните ваш вопрос, нажав на кнопку править

Comment: вот этим воспользуйтесь http://windows-powershell-scripts.blogspot.com.by/2009/08/unix-linux-find-equivalent-in.html

Comment: Defrag посмотрю в понедельник, спасибо. Senior Pomidor в этом вся проблема, файлов (по 30кб -5мб) на более чем 16Тб, потому стандартные способы не работают. Defrag подсказал хорошую идею с "файл был создан\отредактирован х времени назад" к сожалению смогу попробовать его только в понедельник.

Comment: Хотя подумал что ему всеравно придётся просканировать все файлы.. Но посмотрим как сработает.

Comment: Отредактировал, вопрос как сделать это быстрее если по другому никак - актуален, в понедельник попробую что подсказали - отпишусь.

Comment: @YukiA изначально я хотел посоветовать mingw64 и воспользоваться командой find. Но раз нельзя кроме powershell/cmd ничего, то пробуйте Find-ChildItem

Answer (score 1):

Так устроит?

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set idx=0
for /f %%i in ('dir /A:-D /B /O:-D') do (
  copy %%i 1\
  set /a idx= !idx! + 1
  if !idx!==5 exit
)
```

Выполняем команду `dir` с сортировкой файлов по убыванию даты и после первых 5 файлов выходим

Comment: Будет ли он работать для подпапок?

Comment: Для подпапок добавьте ключ `/s`

Comment: попробую в понедельник, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell

1. Самый новый **файл**(!) в текущей папке.

   ```
   dir -File | sort LastWriteTime -Descending | select -First 1
   ```
2. Файлы за **последние 2 дня**:

   ```
   dir -File | where LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDay(-7)
   ```

   Для **`Get-ChildItem`** (она же - **`dir`**) можно указать путь, даже сетевой: `D:\Папка с архивами`, `\\Server\Mail\Incoming\`
3. Комбинируем примеры 1 и 2, чтобы выбрать самые **новые**, но только **за последнюю неделю**:

   ```
   dir -File | where LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDay(-2) | sort LastWriteTime -Descending | select -First 1
   ```
4. Самый новый файл в **каждой** подпапке 1-го уровня (непосредственно дочерняя в текущей)

   ```
   dir -Directory -Recurse -Depth 1 | %{dir $_ -File | sort LastWriteTime -Descending | Select -First 1}
   ```
5. Для копирования добавьте конвеер команды копирования:

   ```
   <# что-то из примеров выше #> | cp -Destination "D:\Папка со свежими файлами\$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd')\"
   ```

   Создаст в нужной папке подпапку с сегодняшней датой и переложит все свежие файлы туда.
6. Для правильного создания путей лучше всего использовать `Join-Path`:

   ```
   ❯ Join-Path 'D:\Где всё лежит' (Get-Date -Format 'yy-MM-dd HH:mm')
   D:\Где всё лежит\20-10-26 15:51
   ```
7. По поводу **где посмотреть**:

   ```
   alias dir,ls,sort,select,where,cp | Get-Help -Online
   ```